# How to get a beep noise after pressing a button in tkinter?

Tags: python, audio, tkinter

I'm trying to get a beep noise after pressing the 'calculate' button but I haven't been able to make it work, I've tried reading and using some tips online but they haven't worked for me, all i need from it is a simple sound but preferably a beep but not a ear piercing one.

My code:

```
import sys
import winsound

from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox


def cal():
    car_value=float(a.get())
    car_sold=float(b.get())

    if car_value < 80000:
        commission=0.015
    elif car_value >=80000 and car_value <=1750000:
        commission=0.0225
    elif car_value >175001:
        commission=0.0279
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Title", "a Tk MessageBox")

    commission_a=car_value*commission+car_sold*129
    labelresult=Label(mgui,text="Your comission is £ %.2f"%commission_a).grid(row=5,column=1)

    return

mgui=Tk()
mgui.wm_iconbitmap('calculator.ico')
a=StringVar()
b=StringVar()

scale = Scale(mgui,variable =b,orient='horizontal').grid(row=2,column=1)
frequency = 2500
duration = 1000
play=winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
## souund plays when window opens but not when button is pressed
mgui.geometry("300x300+300+300")
mgui.title("Commission Calculator")
mbutton=Button(mgui,play,text='Calculate',command=cal).grid(row=4,column=0,sticky="w")
##frequency = 2500
##duration = 1000
##play=winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
mEntry1=Entry(mgui,textvariable=a).grid(row=1,column=1)


eng=Label(mgui,text="Total value of cars sold").grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="W")
ag=Label(mgui,text="Amount of cars sold").grid(row=2,column=0,sticky="W")

menubar=Menu(mgui)


filemenu=Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="New")
filemenu.add_command(label="Open")
filemenu.add_command(label="Save quote")
filemenu.add_command(label="Close",command=mgui.destroy)## does close window
menubar.add_cascade(label='File',menu=filemenu)
mgui.config(menu=menubar)

filemenu=Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="About program")
menubar.add_cascade(label='Help',menu=filemenu)
mgui.config(menu=menubar)
```

Comment: You can do that in tkinter using the universal widget method [`bell()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) — which isn't Windows-specific btw. In this case just add a call to `mgui.beep()` to your `cal()` function (and get rid of all that `winsound` stuff).

Comment: @martineau where in the cal() do I add it?

Comment: Probably at the beginning.

Comment: You can put `winsound.Beep(500, 100)` in your function ``cal()``.